# Proving $\mathscr{\bar{M}}$ is closed under countable unions.

Tags: measure-theory

Let (X $\mathscr{M}$, $\mu$) be a measure space and let $\mathscr{N}$ be the collection of null sets in $\mathscr{M}$. Define $\mathscr{\bar{M}}$ = {E $\cup$ F: E $\in$ $\mathscr{M}$ and F $\subset$ $\mathscr{N}$ for some N $\in$ $\mathscr{N}$}. Prove that $\mathscr{\bar{M}}$ is closed under countable unions.

Here is my dilemma. I understand that the nullsets have a measure of $\mu$(n) = 0. However, it is from here where I don't understand where to go to. As always any help is always appreciated.

Comment: Start with writing down a countable union of elements of $\overline{\mathscr{M}}$: $$\bigcup_{k = 0}^\infty (E_k \cup F_k).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Wouldn't the union of these two sets have a measure value of only E considering F $\subset$ $\mathscr{N}$ and $\mathscr{N}$ is the collection of all null sets and the null set measure is 0?

Comment: $\cup_{k=0}^{\infty}(E_k\cup F_k)=\cup_{k=0}^{\infty}E_k  \cup [(\cup_{k=0}^{\infty} F_k)\setminus \cup_{k=0}^{\infty}E_k ]$,where $\cup_{k=0}^{\infty}E_k \in \mathcal{M}$ and $ [(\cup_{k=0}^{\infty} F_k)\setminus \cup_{k=0}^{\infty}E_k ]  \in  \mathcal{N}$.

Comment: I correct my answer  8 mins ago : $ [(\cup_{k=0}^{\infty}F_k\setminus \cup_{k=0}^{\infty}E_k]\subseteq \cup_{k=0}^{\infty}F_k \in \mathcal{N}$.